# How can I use JSONDecoder to decode a Int to a String?

Tags: ios, swift, string, int, jsondecoder

I'm parsing a `JSON` from an `API`, like this:

```
let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: parsedData) 

// MARK: - Person
struct Person: Codable {
    let position 
    let rank: Int
}
```

The problem is when I want to set the value of a `UILabel` with `rank`, because I want to add a '#', so I have to do it the following way:

```
labelRank.text = "#" + "\(person.rank)"
```

when in reality I wanted to do:

```
labelRank.text = person.rank
```

So in reality I want to have a custom parse from `Int` to `String`. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: What is the type of your position property? Where is your JSON string? BTW SO it is not a code writing service. You should edit your question, add what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a computed property **rankAsString** which would return `"#" + "\(rank)"` in Person struct as follows.

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let position: Int
    let rank: Int
    
    var rankAsString: String {
        return "#" + "\(self.rank)"
    }
}
```

And, then use that to populate label like as follows.

```
labelRank.text = rankAsString
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
struct Person: Codable  {

    var position: Int 
    var rank: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        position = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .position)
        let decodedName = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .rank)
        rank = "# \(decodedName)" 
    }
}
```